# What exactly is the procedure for hanuman fasting praying? Which prayer to recite?

Tags: hanuman

I have started Tuesday fasting. It's been 3 months. But everytime i pray i recite Hanuman chalisa and i think that's not just enough. Is there anything more to include? I pray in the evening as well and my procedure stays the same. I have one meal in a day after my evening prayers (without salt) while playing hanuman bhajans. Am i supposed to put something more in this?

Comment: Why are you fasting? What is your aim to accomplish by this? Why are you trying to please Lord Hanumana? Has your Guru initiated you to do this sadhana or is it self imposed? Assuming from your post this is self imposed. No matter how many intricacies/rules you add yourself the result is going to be minimal at the end if there is no proper guidance..Only proper guided sadhanas followed with proper rules, dedication and bhakti of the deity lead to any visible effects.

Comment: See [this](https://shriramaandhanumanconsciousness.blogspot.com/search/label/Hanuman%20Mantras) sadhana of Hanuman Chalisa(the first one only). **(Note:this is just an example to show how sadhanas are usually done with rules, neither have i performed by this procedure nor do i advise anyone to follow.)** But i found this close to some of the sadhanas i have done/read abt so you can have a look!